# How to implement BRISK using Python and OpenCV to detect features?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, mser

I want to implement `BRISK` using **Python** and **OpenCV** for **Feature Detection and Description** in drone images.

Since `BRISK` is also a descriptor, I want to use its description features to match two images.

How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? This should be very simple if you are just reading the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/dbf/classcv_1_1BRISK.html)

Comment: I haven't tried yet. Since I am new to these openCV and python, i dont really know where to start.

Comment: Set up OpenCV and Python. Use `imread` to read your images. Find features using `cv.BRISK_create` for both images. Match features use `cv.DescriptorMatcher_create` (e.g. BruteForce). An (older) example can be found e.g. [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html) or using google search.

Answer (score 8):

You can perform **Feature Detection and Description** with the **Local Binary Descriptor** `BRISK`, and then, use `Brute Force` or `FLANN` algorithms to do **Feature Matching** using **Python** and **OpenCV**.

In this example, I will show you **Feature Detection and Matching** with `BRISK` through the `Brute Force` algorithm.

First, load the input image and the image that will be used for training.

In this example, we are using those images:

`image1`:

[image]

`image2`:

[image]

```
# Imports
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open and convert the input and training-set image from BGR to GRAYSCALE
image1 = cv.imread(filename = 'image1.jpg',
                   flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

image2 = cv.imread(filename = 'image2.jpg',
                   flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Note that when importing the images, we use the `flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` parameter, because in **OpenCV** the default color mode setting is **BGR**. Therefore, to work with **Descriptors**, we need to convert the color mode pattern from **BGR** to **grayscale**.

Now we will use the `BRISK` algorithm:

```
# Initiate BRISK descriptor
BRISK = cv.BRISK_create()

# Find the keypoints and compute the descriptors for input and training-set image
keypoints1, descriptors1 = BRISK.detectAndCompute(image1, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = BRISK.detectAndCompute(image2, None)
```

The **features** detected by the `BRISK` algorithm can be combined to find objects or patterns that are similar between different images.

Now we will use the `Brute Force` algorithm:

```
# create BFMatcher object
BFMatcher = cv.BFMatcher(normType = cv.NORM_HAMMING,
                         crossCheck = True)

# Matching descriptor vectors using Brute Force Matcher
matches = BFMatcher.match(queryDescriptors = descriptors1,
                          trainDescriptors = descriptors2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x: x.distance)

# Draw first 15 matches
output = cv.drawMatches(img1 = image1,
                        keypoints1 = keypoints1,
                        img2 = image2,
                        keypoints2 = keypoints2,
                        matches1to2 = matches[:15],
                        outImg = None,
                        flags = cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

And the output will be:

[image]

This technique is widely used in image recovery applications, motion tracking, object detection, recognition and tracking, 3D object reconstruction, among others. And you can easily modify the way you load the images. In this way, this technique can easily be applied to your problem.

To learn more about **Detection**, **Description**, and **Feature Matching** techniques, **Local Feature Descriptors**, **Local Binary Descriptors**, and algorithms for **Feature Matching**, I recommend the following repositories on **GitHub**:

- https://github.com/whoisraibolt/Feature-Detection-and-Description
- https://github.com/whoisraibolt/Feature-Detection-and-Matching

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe is the best solution, please, mark this answer as accepted! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I've combined all of the code snippets into a single gist for ease of use: https://gist.github.com/rinogo/0e7124d5da3c6abd9b9cd6e133ff00fb